# Android PID issue

Tags: android, linux, process, pid

I've found an interesting fact that one of the development.

I tried to use the pid of the installed application in my phone.

It was able to use the information of the installed application using a getInstalledApplications of packagemanager class. But the pid could not be seen.

pid was provided by RunningAppProcessInfo of Activitymanager class.

There are some questions.

1. Does pid is generated when the application is executed?
2. Is the pid of each application is a fixed value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.`Yes`. PIDs are assigned at runtime of app.

2.`No`. PID of each app is not a fixed value, its changes during runtime. However `UID` of each app is a fixed value which is assigned during installation of app.

Comment: Hi @altaf, During automation testing my Android app PID getting changed each time when app minimize and maximize after a certain period of time. Is it expected behavior or issue?